# Bloquear fechas en Datepicker

Tags: php, javascript

Estoy usando este datepicker  https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/

En la vista recibo este array de fechas que quiero deshabilitar.

```
array:8 [▼
  0 => {#252 ▼
    +"area_id": "2"
    +"title": "asd"
    +"start": "2018-08-30"
    +"end": "2018-08-31"
    +"acept": "1"
  }
  1 => {#253 ▼
    +"area_id": "2"
    +"title": "asdf"
    +"start": "2019-03-12"
    +"end": "2019-03-15"
    +"acept": "1"
  }
  2 => {#254 ▼
    +"area_id": "2"
    +"title": "asdf"
    +"start": "2019-03-03"
    +"end": "2019-03-05"
    +"acept": "1"
  }
```

En la documentación me pone que tengo que hacer esto:

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  disable: [
    { from: [2016,2,14], to: [2016,2,27] }
  ]
})
```

Mi pregunta entonces es, como podría pasarle las fechas en el formato from.. to... He intentado hacer esto:

```
var daysData = <?= json_encode($dataFechas) ?>;
var newA = [];
for( j of daysData){
  let start = moment(j["start"]);
  let end   = moment(j["end"]);

  for (let m = moment(start); m.diff(end, 'days') <= 0; m.add(1, 'days')) {
    newA[m.format('DD/MM/YYYY')] = j;
  }
}
```

Pero el formato que me devuelve no debe de ser correcto y el picker no aparece.

La cosa es que intente eliminar el resto de items del array pero necesitaba `acept` para poder pintarlo en diferentes colores, según el valor del campo. Si es 1 en Rojo, en 0 naranja, y si no hay coincidencias en verde.

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes los campos start y end definidos como fechas en el modelo en Laravel, puedes formatearlo con Carbon directamente:

```
$start->format('Y,m,d')
```

Y pasas esos valores directamente al datepicker:

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  disable: [
    { from: [{{$start->format('Y,m,d')}}], to: [{{$end->format('Y,m,d')}}] }
  ]
})
```

En caso que no funcione por intentar pasar un string como array, puedes entonces obtener cada valor por aparte, también con Carbon:

```
$start->year;
$start->month;
$start->day;
```

Comment: Si quieres te pongo el codigo del controlador para que veas como lo obtengo, pero hago un DB para traer los datos de la bd y hago un bucle or para insertarlo en el objeto y se lo paso a la vista, el resultado es el array que puse, no queria alterar mucho mas la logica del controlador. pero si es mas simple no me importaria, creo que siendo asi, no esta en cabron no? Gracias por tu respuesta @Shaz

Comment: Carbon es el nombre correcto, y por lo visto no creo que esté en Carbon.

Comment: Disculpa, me confundi al escribirlo, y siendo asi, tendre que mandar solo esos datos en un array